# How to edit DBF and NTX files

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010, dbf

I want to add a register into a DBF file using java. I can do that but when I try to see the register into the system that use the DBF file nothing appears. I was trying to do this manually, opening the dbf file and adding one more row then go to the system to show this new data but it's the same result, nothing happen.
I have some .ntx files in the same folder and I sure this can indicate something maybe the relation between primary keys or something.
Does anyone tried to edit a DBF and NTX file in order to add a new register?

Answer (score 0):

I believe .NTX files are associated with dBASE.  What you may be encountering is that when you add a record to the raw table, the corresponding "NTX" (Index file) is not opened at the same time and thus if viewing the records via the original data system, you might want to try and "reindex" the tables and see if the record appears or not.  If they DO show up, then yes, the index is the culprit... its not being updated.  Since I don't know java and opening dbf files, I can't guide you more on that, but at least a start direction for you to look more into.

Comment: Thanks for you response, So we are at the same level. I can open and add one more record and its fine, but the system that use this data does not recognize them thus the ntx files are not being updated. How can I "reindex" this NTX files?

Comment: @RicardoGonzales, I'm not sure of the originating system.  However, in FoxPro (Visual Foxpro) and using C# with OleDB Provider, when you query a table (insert,update,delete), the corresponding index files are opened at the same time so they stay in-synch with the data.  Sorry I can't direct you more on your specific situation.